# Htaccess redirect for old urls on wordpress installation with new file structure

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I had to update the file structure of a site. all is working fine, but I want to set up some redirects to redirect old URLs to the new version.

Old URL: www.example.com/wp/test-page

New URL: www.example.com/test-page

How do I set up a redirect to catch all instances of URLs containing 'wp' and redirect to the corresponding URL without?

Regards
A

Comment: There are millions of examples for this here on SO and out in the internet. I assume you tried to implement the rules yourself. Since you ask here I further assume that you ran into issues you fail to solve yourself. For us to be able to help you with that we need you to explain what exactly your issue is and what your current implementation is, so the redirection rules you implemented yourself.

Comment: You assume correctly. Some have reverted me to just www.example.com, others have broken the site. I shall keep on searching so

Comment: As written: I suggest you simply add your current rules, so that we can offer you specific help. Thanks.

Comment: Ok I have fixed it. I was using the correct Rewrite rule, I just needed to put it before the default wordpress mod_rewrites

Comment: Glad to hear that. Have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Ok I managed to find the solution. I had the correct rules, I just need to put them before the default Wordpress rewrites...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^wp/(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```